Tkinter Application: Color Formatting & Disabling entry widget not working
I have a rather large tkinter application that will be a dedicated work personnel scheduling system for my job. The schedule contains a grid of entry widgets in the amount of the number of days in a month, depending on the month of the schedule selected. In each entry management will enter the HR code for the person in their day to day.
Depending on a persons access level, they can login with their credentials to view and manager personnel roles, or simply view in read-only if they do not have the required access. picture for context:
work schedule
Currently, I am trying to ensure that when viewed in read-only, the entry widgets are disabled; however, I want them to still be colored as if they are enabled. To do this, I'm using the following code with an imported function outside the class. The class code is rather long so I'll only attach the applicable parts for reference:
data_loaded method in ScheduleHrsFrame class (the frame that contains the schedule entries. This method takes the passed data -> list in parameter and applies it to the entries
    def data_loaded(self, data):
        """
        Callback function to handle the loaded data.

        This method is called by the WorkbookDataLoader thread when the data is loaded.
        It updates the existing frames with the loaded data or creates new frames if needed.
        """
        # Destroy existing frames before creating new ones
        self.destroy_frames()

        if self.schedule_type == "Overtime":
            frames = []
            for i, (name, starting_asking_hours, starting_working_hours, hours_data) in enumerate(data):
                frame = HrsMatrixFrame(self.inner_frame, name, self.hdr_date_grid,
                                    self.ranking_frame, starting_asking_hours,
                                    starting_working_hours)
                frame.pack(pady=5, fill="x")
                frames.append(frame)

                for j, (working_hours, asking_hours) in enumerate(hours_data):
                    working_hours_entry = frame.working_hours_entries[j]
                    working_hours_entry.delete(0, tk.END)
                    working_hours_entry.insert(0, working_hours)

                    asking_hours_entry = frame.asking_hours_entries[j]
                    asking_hours_entry.delete(0, tk.END)
                    asking_hours_entry.insert(0, asking_hours)

                # Update column sums and labels for Overtime frames
                frame.update_column_sums(None)
                frame.labels[0].config(text=name)

            self.frames = frames
            # TODO: May need error handling here
            if self.access_level == "read-only":
                for frame in self.frames:
                    lock_widgets(frame)

        else:
            frames = []
            for i, (name, role_data) in enumerate(data):
                frame = WorkScheduleMatrixFrame(self.inner_frame, name, self.hdr_date_grid,
                                                self.ranking_frame)
                frame.pack(pady=5, fill="x")
                frames.append(frame)

                for j, role in enumerate(role_data):
                    entry = frame.crew_member_role_entries[j]
                    entry.delete(0, tk.END)
                    entry.insert(0, role)
                    apply_entry_color_specs(entry, role)

            self.work_schedule_frames = frames
            
            # TODO: Entry widgets should disabled but remain appropriately colored 
            # depending on string value. A bug is preventing the widgets from being
            # disabled after the color function is executed. No errors generated.
            if self.access_level == "read-only":
                for frame in self.work_schedule_frames:
                    lock_and_color_entry_widgets(frame)

        self.display_legend()
        self.update_scrollbar()
        self.get_labels()
        self.adjust_canvas_size()

functions:
def lock_and_color_entry_widgets(container):
    """
    Lock (disable) all Entry widgets and apply formatting in the given container.

    Args:
        container (tk.BaseWidget): The container widget.
    """
    for child in container.winfo_children():
        if isinstance(child, (tk.Entry, ctk.CTkEntry)):
            entry_text = child.get()
            bg_color, fg_color = apply_entry_color_specs(child, entry_text)
            child.configure(disabledbackground=bg_color, disabledforeground=fg_color)
            child.configure(state=tk.DISABLED)

def assignment_code_formatting(frame, label, code_text, color_specs):
    """
    Format the WSMatrix Legend labels with the appropriate formatting.

    Args:
        frame (widget): The passed frame.
        label (widget): The passed label.
        code_text (str): The text contained in the label.
        color_specs (dict): color specifications {code_text:{bg:color, text:color}}
    """
    if code_text in color_specs:
        frame.configure(fg_color=color_specs[code_text]["frame"])
        label.configure(fg_color=color_specs[code_text]["label_bg"], text_color=color_specs[code_text]["label_text"])
    else:
        frame.configure(fg_color="blue")
        label.configure(fg_color="blue", text_color="white")

Constant Variables:
COLOR_SPECS = {
    "FC":{"frame":"#e26b0a", "label_bg":"#e26b0a", "label_text":"yellow"}, 
    "HT":{"frame":"#c0504d", "label_bg":"#c0504d", "label_text":"white"}, 
    "FTF":{"frame":"#ddd9c4", "label_bg":"#ddd9c4", "label_text":"black"}, 
    "ST":{"frame":"#d9d9d9", "label_bg":"#d9d9d9", "label_text":"black"}, 
    "BB":{"frame":"#0071c4", "label_bg":"#0071c4", "label_text":"white"}, 
    "G":{"frame":"#c4d79b", "label_bg":"#c4d79b", "label_text":"black"}, 
    "R":{"frame":"#ffff00", "label_bg":"#ffff00", "label_text":"black"}, 
    "SC":{"frame":"#b1a0c7", "label_bg":"#b1a0c7", "label_text":"black"}, 
    "SA":{"frame":"#c5d9eb", "label_bg":"#c5d9eb", "label_text":"black"}, 
    "T":{"frame":"#00b050", "label_bg":"#00b050", "label_text":"white"}, 
    "BH":{"frame":"#0097b9", "label_bg":"#0097b9", "label_text":"black"}, 
    "V":{"frame":"#00b0f0", "label_bg":"#00b0f0", "label_text":"white"}, 
    "PC":{"frame":"#00b0ef", "label_bg":"#00b0ef", "label_text":"black"}, 
    "ERT":{"frame":"#ff0000", "label_bg":"#ff0000", "label_text":"yellow"}, 
    "BT":{"frame":"#00ffff", "label_bg":"#00ffff", "label_text":"black"}, 
    "M":{"frame":"#ffffff", "label_bg":"#ffffff", "label_text":"black"}, 
    "JD":{"frame":"#d8e4bc", "label_bg":"#d8e4bc", "label_text":"black"}, 
    "SK":{"frame":"#da9694", "label_bg":"#da9694", "label_text":"black"}, 
    "SW":{"frame":"#4e3b63", "label_bg":"#4e3b63", "label_text":"white"}, 
    "OC":{"frame":"#ffc000", "label_bg":"#ffc000", "label_text":"black"},
}


I ended up figuring out the issue after some troubleshooting. The entry widgets were contained in frames individually, so they were basically skipped. Setting up a recursive loop in the lock function ensured the entry was not skipped in the loop:
def lock_and_color_entry_widgets(container):
    """
    Lock (disable) all Entry widgets and apply formatting in the given container and its child frames.

    Args:
        container (tk.BaseWidget): The container widget.
    """
    for child in container.winfo_children():
        if isinstance(child, (tk.Entry, ctk.CTkEntry)):
            entry_text = child.get()
            if entry_text in COLOR_SPECS:
                bg_color = COLOR_SPECS[entry_text]["label_bg"]
                fg_color = COLOR_SPECS[entry_text]["label_text"]
            else:
                bg_color = "white"
                fg_color = "black"
            child.configure(state=tk.DISABLED, disabledbackground=bg_color, disabledforeground=fg_color)
        elif isinstance(child, tk.Frame):
            lock_and_color_entry_widgets(child)  # Recursively call the function for child frames

